# Não consigo usar o JsonConverter em Json.Net com Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, serialização, json.net

Então, estou desenvolvendo um sistema visual de programação em `FSM`, e para serialização, usei `Json.Net`, até ai, tudo bem, funcionou corretamente, porém, precisei serializar `UnityObjects` e as coisas ficaram complicadas, eu queria serializar apenas a referencia no editor, mas ele tentava serializar o objeto.
Então criei um `JsonConverter` e adicionei ao `JsonSettings`, como deve ser, porém, ao serializar, tudo funcionava bem, e ele serializava, mas ao `deserializar`, ele nem sequer chama o método, eu acredito que seja devido a estar serializando um `'int'`, mas já tentei de todas as formas pensáveis, e não consegui, espero que alguém possa me dar uma luz sobre isto.

**Código:**

```
public class UObjectConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert (Type objectType)
    {
        var uobj = typeof(UnityEngine.Object);
        return objectType == uobj || uobj.IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
    public override void WriteJson (JsonWriter writer, object value,    JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var uobj = value as UnityEngine.Object;
        int id;
        if (uobj == null)
            id = 0;
        else
            id = uobj.GetInstanceID ();
        var type = typeof(Object);
        if (uobj != null)
            type = uobj.GetType ();
        writer.WriteValue(id);
    }
    public override object ReadJson (JsonReader reader, Type objectType,
                                     object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        int id = (int)((long)reader.Value);
        if (id == 0)
            return null;
        else
            return MainClass.GetObject(id);
    }
}
```

Bom, aqui está um exemplo de codigo, antes deixe-me explicar, dentro da classe 'AIScriptData' existe a lista com os 'States', nesses 'States', existe basicamente uma lista com 'Actions' e o nome, cada 'Action' é basicamente um tipo com um metodo virtual 'Execute()', e os derivados podem usar seus proprios fields e etc, quando se quer referenciar uma variavel ou valor, utiliza-se a classe 'Value', que pode referenciar um 'Variable', ou ter um 'object' de valor proprio.
A 'Variable' tem um id('string') e um valor('object'), alem de um tipo('Type').
A outra lista no 'AIScriptData' é sobre 'Variable', basicamente, é isso.
O tipo 'DarkJson' é apenas um tipo que criei que utiliza a classe JsonConvert.

**Código:**

```
public AIScriptData script;
public string json;
public void Save()
{
  // Até aqui tudo bem, ele serializa corretamente
  json = DarkJson.Serialize(script);
} 
public void Load()
{
  // Aqui ocorre o problema, ele simplesmente deserializa um inteiro
  // ao inves do transform, como deveria ser.
  script = DarkJson.Deserialize<AIScriptData>(json);
}
```

Comment: Adicione um exemplo com um Json e a chamada do `ReadJson()` que você está executando.

Comment: Codigo de Exemplo Adicionado.

Answer (score 0):

A Unity tem uma classe própria para Json que é a JsonUtility, recomendo que dê uma olhada mas resumidamente você precisa saber de 4 coisas:

- O Objeto saída/entrada precisa der um [Serializable] ou possuir atributos Serializable da Unity, sendo que se você criar como [Serializable] não pode ter como hierarquia a classe MonoBehaviour.
- Utilize o JsonUtility.ToJson(obj) para pegar e serializar o objeto inteiro em uma string Json.
- Utilize o JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(obj) para carregar o json e sobrescever qualquer informação que vier.
- Utilize o JsonUtility.FromJson(json) para inicializar o seu obj

Espero que isso ajude